# How to create specific footers for specific pages in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, jetpack

So - I've been running around ways to do this and get half way there which is a bit infuriating!

Using jetpack portfolio - I want to show normal categories in my blog section and posts, and jetpack project types on the portfolio page and single projects.

My current code looks like this - and shows the jetpack portfolio types for the first post on the archive-jetpack-portfolio, and display correctly on the single project. but doesn;t work at all for the blog posts.

```php
<?php 
  if (is_page_template('page-blog.php','single.php','index.php' )){
    wp_list_categories(array(
      'show_option_all' => '', 
      'title_li' => '',
      'separator' => '%20',
      'orderby' => 'name'
    )); 
  } else {
    the_terms($posts->ID, 'jetpack-portfolio-type'); 
  }      
?>
```

So if these pages - show this, else show this. I know the $post-ID is where it's falling over for the archive page. Don't know why the blog bit isn't working.

Hope that's enough to go on. I bow to your infinite knowledge hive-mind!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on custom template you have created you will need to call for custom footer using get_footer function. Here you can read more about [get_footer](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_footer) function. You just need to specify $name parameter.

Monika

Comment: Ah! Seems obvious now. That solves one problem!

Now just the the_terms($posts->ID, 'jetpack-portfolio-type');

Comment: Have used

<?php 
            // list terms in a given taxonomy
            $taxonomy = 'jetpack-portfolio-type';
            $tax_terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );
 
            foreach ( $tax_terms as $tax_term ) {
            echo '<a href="../project-type/'.$tax_term->slug.'"><li class="nav d-inline" style="margin-left: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 10px; list-style: none;" data-filter=".'. $tax_term->slug.'">' . $tax_term->slug .'</li></a>';
            }
        ?>